# Check object for elements inside it on Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

There is a drop-down list of items. If `send` button is pressed, the elements of the object are handled and I get a certain result. I want to check if the object is empty, then redirect to another page?

The code:

`html`:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart / form-data">
    <select id = 'sel' name = 'sel' class = "selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search = "true">
      {% for elem in elements%}
        <option id = "val" value = "{{elem}}"> {{elem}} </option>
      {% endfor%}
    </select>
    <button> Send </button>
</form>
```

`python:`

```
@ app.route ('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index ():
if request.method == 'GET':
return render_template ('index.html', elements = elements) # get all the elements on the page
elif request.method == 'POST':
    docs = request.form.getlist ('sel') # here I get the items selected from the list
    result = handler.dosomething (docs) # handler function
return render_template ('handler.html', result = result)
else:
pass
```

How to check if `docs` is empty and there are no selected elements inside this variable, then when the button is pressed, redirect to another page, for example `error.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more if statement. See below:

```
@ app.route ('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index ():
if request.method == 'GET':
return render_template ('index.html', elements = elements) # get all the elements on the page
elif request.method == 'POST':
    docs = request.form.getlist ('sel')
    if len(docs)>0:
        result = handler.dosomething (docs)
        return render_template('handler.html', result = result)
    else:
        return render_template('error.html')
```